# Seeking data for image fusion of satellite and UAV/ drone data?

Tags: geospatial, images

I'm new to Remote Sensing and Data Processing, and interested in fusion.

Where do I find georeferenced data that can be fused together?

It can be either of the following:

```
Satellite image and drone image (multi/ hyper spectral)
Satellite image (multi/ hyper spectral) and spectroradiometer data (quantitative)
```

For satellites, I think I can go with Landsat images, but which one should I use/ where do I find the corresponding second data to fuse together.

Comment: You didn't say where or the location you are seeking in ?

Answer (score 1):

A good starting place to begin might be to look at the Sentinel Missions with Sentinel 1, 2 and 3. You can see details [**here.**](https://www.esa.int/Our_Activities/Observing_the_Earth/Copernicus/Overview4)

This data is freely available for download from a few platforms but I would recommend the Rocket Project from Mashup for any new people to remote sensing, which can be found [**here.**](https://mapshup.com/projects/rocket/#/home) An important thing to consider is the temporal resolution of the data because this may cause unwanted and unexpected results after fusion implementation.

Sentinel 1 uses radar, Sentinel 2 is multi spectral and Sentinel 3 has a wide range of instruments but the one you may be interested in is for land surface temperature.

You can then use the Sentinel Application Platform (SNAP) which is free to download to help you pre-process them and can be found [**here.**](http://step.esa.int/main/download/).

Other than that it is just a case of choosing any other software you might want to use and having a look online and in books for some detailed workflows.